# HOW: When the article is commented, go up that post in WP

Tags: wordpress

When a new comment is made on an old article, I want it to go above that article in Wordpress. How can i do that?

Comment: You might want to reword this in the form of a question.

Comment: Im so sorry. I edited my post.